# Is this a safe model for authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication

My nodejs server receives requests from clients. This request either includes a `cpuId` query parameter, in which case the client is identifying itself, or provides no such parameter (which suggests it is a newcomer):

```
let parseRequestData = async req => { /* ... */ };
let lookupUserByCpuId = cpuId => { /* ... */ };
let initNewUserWithRandomCpuId = () => { /* ... */ };
let removeExistingUser = user => { /* ... */ };
let respondToUserRequest = (user, path, query, body) => { /* ... */ };
let server = require('http').createServer(async (req, res) => {

  // `path` could look like "/people"
  // `query` could look like { cpuId: '183270232873', filter: 'age<=30', sort: 'ascending:firstName' }
  // `body` is a json body in case a body is relevant to the request
  let { path, query, body } = await parseRequestData(req);

  let user = null;
  let claimsToHaveUser = query.hasOwnProperty('cpuId');
  if (claimsToHaveUser) {
    user = lookupUserByCpuId(query.cpuId);
    if (!user) { res.writeHead(400); res.end('Invalid cpuId'); return; }
  } else {
    user = initNewUserWithRandomCpuId();
    user.confirmationTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      removeExistingUser(user);
    }, 60 * 60 * 1000);
    // When the user confirms email, cell #, etc, we'll clear this timeout
  }

  // If we get here, `user` is instantiated!

  try {
    let jsonResponse = respondToUserRequest(user, path, query, body);
  } catch(err) {
    res.writeHead(500); res.end('An error occurred'); return;
  }

  if (claimsToHaveUser) jsonResponse.cpuId = user.cpuId;

  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse));

});
```

Clients are free to make an initial request without a `cpuId` value. The response to this will always include a freshly created `cpuId`. The client then may include that `cpuId` in every request going forwards - this will allow the client to tie multiple requests to the same account on the server.

The `cpuId` values involved are kept private, and are never sent by the server except for in the very first request which initializes the `cpuId`.

**Is this a safe authentication model? What are some security concerns here?**

Comment: Anyone can guess `cpuId` and make requests as someone else.

Comment: Maybe, but it's trivial to make the `cpuId` format much less guessable, like 128-bit uuid.

Comment: In this case, it should be necessary to use it over SSL/HTTPS.